# Difference in Solicit and unsolicit messages/events in MFC?

Tags: windows, mfc, visual-c++

Can someone pls tell me do we have solic & unsolic message/events in MFC or window programming?

In devices solic response and unsolic response is said as immediate response (like acknowledgement to commands) and late response (generated without any further commands being sent) respectively. 
Likewise can we say events as solic / unsolic based on immediate occurrence and late occurrence?

Comment: Could you provide some more context, rather than just "I have seen"? *Where* have you seen it?

Comment: I have reframed the question accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 unsolic
```

PostMessage call: Posts the message and doesn't waits for its execution and immediately goes to process next line in code.

```
 solic
```

SendMessage call: Sends the message and waits for its execution before going to next line in code.

Comment: Got the answer from other sources and I have added it.